# @upstash/redis scan command

Tags: javascript, redis, next.js

Using @upstash/redis node client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@upstash/redis) im trying to run the scan command (that should be supported, according to docs), but im not able to set the options:

```
const redis = new Redis({
  url: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL,
  token: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_RO_REST_TOKEN,
});
const result = await redis.scan(0);
```

This way it works, but when i try to add MATCH or COUNT (it says it is  ScanCommandOptions type) i get no results. I tried several ways

```
const result = await redis.scan(0, MATCH, 'title*');

const result = await redis.scan(0, (MATCH, 'title*'));

const result = await redis.scan(0, {MATCH:'title*'});
```

but it looks these are not the correct way, i cant find any example, any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
scan(cursor: number, opts: {
  match?: string
  count?: number
  type?: string
})
```

For more details, see this [Github Issue](https://github.com/upstash/upstash-redis/issues/159)